# Javascript ReferenceError: reloadPriceOfSingleProduct is not defined

Tags: magento-1.9, product, configurable-product, javascript, option

I get following errors in console of my browser if I change options on a Product under magento 1.9.3.3 :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined
at klass.initialize (prototype.js:1743)
at klass.initialize (prototype.js:429)
at new klass (prototype.js:101)
at klass.Product.Config.updateData (configurable.js:450)
at klass.Product.Config.configureElement (configurable.js:269)
at klass.Product.Config.configureForValues (configurable.js:332)
at klass.initialize (configurable.js:105)
at klass (prototype.js:101)


Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'processEmpty' of undefined
at PRODUCTNAME.HTML

Uncaught ReferenceError: StockStatus is not defined
at PRODUCTNAME.HTML

configurable.js:348 Uncaught ReferenceError: reloadPriceOfSingleProduct is not defined
at klass.Product.Config.configureImage (configurable.js:348)
at HTMLImageElement.<anonymous> (prototype.js:391)
at HTMLImageElement.responder (prototype.js:5598)
```

I tried to put old files (prototype.js, app/design/base,default,rwd folders)

Cleaned cache, index ... nothing helped

Anybody an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `reloadPriceOfSingleProduct` does not exist in the file [`configurable.js`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.9.3.3/js/varien/configurable.js), but I guess you figured that out by now.
For that matter, the function does not exist in the whole vanilla project.
I'm just shooting in the dark here, but I think you had one extension that you disabled, or some custom theme and you minified the js files. Try to unminify them or minify them again to see if the problem reproduces.
Look in all the files for that method to get a better view of where that comes from.